# Converting my Keyboards Hotkeys for Email, Browser, etc... into Media Control Keys

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

The new keyboard doesn't have keys for media control (the image on Amazon was small). I want to re-purpose the keys for e-mail, sleep, calculator, etc... into media control keys.

This is my keyboard:

[Keyboard-Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-920-002733-K200-Media-Keyboard/dp/B003R2OUYK)

I've researched `AutoHotKey` and found that this is possible; however, I am not sure how to fully implement it. I cannot find any way to identify these keys to the program. I would be happy if you could tell me how to identify these keys to the program and how to get it to respond in the correct way. That is, next track and previous track selection.

Answer (score 2):

Autohotkey has built in support for some multimedia keys.

```
Browser_Back
Browser_Forward
Browser_Refresh
Browser_Stop
Browser_Search
Browser_Favorites
Browser_Home
Volume_Mute
Volume_Down
Volume_Up
Media_Next
Media_Prev
Media_Stop
Media_Play_Pause
Launch_Mail
Launch_Media
Launch_App1
Launch_App2
```

Use them with a send command, example:

```
F11::Send,{Media_Play_Pause}
```

If you keyboard had special keys you will have to consult the [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) on that.